# User Input + Random Word and Number printing

Tags: ruby, methods

So I have code:

```
puts 'What is your name?(Enter in field below)'
input = gets.chomp
puts 'end'
occupationslist = ['Engineer', 'Clerk', 'Doctor', 'Demolition Expert', 'Athlete', 'None',]
oclistlength = occupationslist.length
rand1 = rand(oclistlength)
occupation = ocupationslist[rand1]
def occupations
  puts input
  puts 'Occupation: ' + occupation
  puts 'Rating: ' + rand(1-12).to_s  
end
occupations
```

It is supposed to display your name(that you entered), a random occupation, and a random rating but I don't know what is wrong with it.
This is the satisfactory output:

```
prints "What is your name?".
(gets user input)
prints out the input.
prints out a random 'occupation'(from the list in the array above).
prints out the 'Rating: ' - a random number from 0 to 12.
```

Comment: Us either--what are the symptoms? What's supposed to happen? What happens?

Comment: The [SO posting FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-’’ask) states that questions should **be specific**. You provided neither details nor context, expecting people to (a) guess what you *intended* the code to do, (b) guess (or run) the code to determine what it *actually* did, (c) guess a probable delta between the two, and (d) explain it in a way that makes sense to you. Does that seem like a reasonable way to approach asking for help? I'd suggest it doesn't, as evidenced by the voting--YMMV.

Comment: I'd like to delete this question but I can't

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention and ask them to delete it (no guarantees, although it's poor enough they might), or edit the question so it's meaningful.

Comment: @Dave do you waste _all_ of your time criticizing my questions?

Comment: I'd guess I waste about as much time trying to help you be a good SO citizen as the time of ours you waste. I haven't looked at any of your questions since yesterday when I provided you with a link to a list of Ruby operators--~15 hours ago, according to SO. So nope, not even close to all my time. It's unfortunate you view people trying to help in such a disdainful manner--it's not like I'm the only one that has issues with your approach, as evidenced by what's happened.

Comment: WHAT APPROACH? It is the **regular** approach. I ask a question here and I ask for help(to debug it). WHAT APPROACH?

Comment: No, it *isn't* the "regular approach", and the differences in voting between your last two questions compared with your others should be clear evidence of that. When you ask a question, as pointed out by Emil, you need to be explicit and precise. It doesn't work? Okay, *what* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? How can we *tell* that it's not doing what it's supposed to? You've been given a couple useful resources about how to ask good questions--I'd suggest re-examining them and see how it might apply to your last two questions, which were *not* explicit, precise, or well-formulated.

Comment: Simply dumping some code and saying "It doesn't work and I don't know why" is silly. Adding "it's supposed to do this" isn't much better, because we don't know what it *does* do. What are the precise symptoms of failure? How does that compare to the expected output? What have you tried to fix it? You need to *help* us help you, particularly since you're asking for *free* help--don't make people jump through *unnecessary* hoops. We *like* to help. We *enjoy* programming. We *want* to educate. We *don't* want someone to just dump a bunch of shit on us and make us guess everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` and `occupation` are defined outside the scope of the `occupations`function. Either declare it as a global variable with `$input` and `$occupation`, declare it inside the function or pass the variables as arguments to the function (as Lee suggested):

```
puts 'What is your name?(Enter in field below)'
$input = gets.chomp
puts 'end'
occupationslist = ['Engineer', 'Clerk', 'Doctor', 'Demolition Expert', 'Athlete', 'None',]
oclistlength = occupationslist.length
rand1 = rand(oclistlength)
$occupation = occupationslist[rand1]
def occupations
  puts $input
  puts 'Occupation: ' + $occupation
  puts 'Rating: ' + rand(1-12).to_s  
end
occupations
```

Besides, there was a typo: in `occupation = occupationslist[rand1]` instead of oc**c**upationslist[rand1] you wrote ocupationslist[rand1] (without the 'c').

Comment: Or, even better, pass input and occupation as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, the program was written by me for fun and was only supposed to function in an entertaining way. I found the capitalization error 5 mins after I posted the question but I knew nothing of the global varibles. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Using globals for parameter passing is a bad idea. Globals are discouraged for *anything* by the Ruby community. Why not just use parameters?