# Sorting program in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Basically I'm trying to create a BASIC sorting program in ruby without using *.sort* .
Here's my code so far:

```
def optsort
@@a = 0
@@aa= 1
@@b = unsorted.size
@@smallestnum
@@ssmallestnum

while b !=1
if unsorted[a] <= unsorted[b] then
@@smallestnum = unsorted[b]
else @@smallestnu = unsorted[a]
end




@@a = @@a + 
@@aa = @@a + 1
b = b - 1
end
```

Please help me with the code.
ALSO: I get those error messages when I run it:

```
(eval):465: (eval):465: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):465: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

The code is supposed to sort the numbers from least to greatest.

Comment: No, you will need to learn how to debug code. Besides, this looks like a learning exercise, so what good does it make to ask a broad "fix my code" question? Where's the learning in that?

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for an instant 'walktrough' answer, I just want some help. I have just sat there coding for 2 days trying to figure it out. If you understand what I mean

Comment: What happens? What works? What doesn't work? [We just went through this exercise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145075/method-newbie-i-dont-know-how-to-debug-it) :( Also, I find it difficult to read the code without indentation and excess comments, but others may have different opinions regarding that.

Comment: But you haven't said what the problem is! Should we *guess* what you need help with? All you have done is posting a bunch of code without any description of your problem whatsoever. You haven't even said what sorting algorithm you're trying to implement.

Comment: It might also help if you mention which sorting algorithm you're trying to implement, what you're using as a reference implementation (if anything), etc. because even with the comments it's not clear how you're trying to implement the actual sort.

Comment: What's `<<==` supposed to be? A less-than (`<`)?

Comment: ? I thought you'd figure it out... anyway: If the first element in the array if bigger than the second then the current smallestnumber variable (numsmall) then I'm gonna do that in the loop and put the numsmall in the sorted array as I go, I guess that's a bad algorithm but it is still a WIP

Comment: Is this homework? This is the third time I've seen this same question from different people in the past few days.

Comment: Stan, why should anybody need to "figure out" your question? Ask the question and take your time to explain it! Be [precise](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) and [explicit](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#explicit). Most people answering here won't copy your code and try to run it, we read your problem description and run the code in our heads trying to see where things goes wrong.

Comment: Well, why should I waste 2 hours searching for an answer? So far the only similar questions were sorting WORDS or using the _.sort_ method. So, why not?

Comment: @Moderatorpleasedeletethis There's no meaningful difference between sorting numbers or words; the algorithm would be the same--and there are *tons* of examples, in many languages, showing tons of algorithms. The issue isn't, however, one of *what* you're trying to do--it's with the question itself.

Comment: Am I missing the 2nd part of that?

Comment: @Moderatorpleasedeletethis Yes, it would appear you are. And now you're adding `@@` variables, in a method--throwing random syntactical elements at a problem is only going to make things worse. Consider looking at something like [this](http://philcrissman.com/2010/07/18/how-not-to-write-sorting-algorithms-in-ruby/) or [this](http://eigenclass.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-algs-in-ruby.html) as a place to start writing sorts--right now you're kind of flailing at both coding and asking questions that will be responded to.

Comment: @Moderatorpleasedeletethis Editing your two down-voted questions is likely hopeless; I'd start over. But here's the thing--don't just say "help me with the code". Describe precisely what isn't working, what your expectations are *in detail* (e.g., not just "it should sort the numbers"--no shit, you're writing a sort algorithm, unless it's a bogosort or random sort, we assume you want them in *some* order), and so on.

Comment: @Moderatorpleasedeletethis Also, take the time to indent your code properly, trim unnecessary elements (e.g., useless whitespace), etc. If you need to describe what the code is supposed to, put a comment at the beginning of a block--not after every single line. Name variables so it's obvious what they are--don't make us think any more than we need to. Consider reading esr's [how to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) thoroughly, re-visit the SO FAQ I linked to yesterday, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if unsorted[0] <<== unsorted[1] then numsmall = unsorted[a] 
               ^
(eval):51: syntax error, unexpected kTHEN, expecting kEND
```

That little `^` points to first problem here.  `<<==` is not a legal operator in ruby, hence the syntax error. Perhaps you mean "less than or equal to" which is `<=`?

```
if unsorted[a] <= unsorted[b]
```

Also, indentation will help you understand the flow better, try rewriting that like this:

```
if unsorted[a] <= unsorted[b]
  numsmall == unsorted[a]
else
  numsmall = unsorted[b]
end
```

Comment: @Stan [Ruby operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). You might want to consider some sort of codified Ruby resources and tutorials--it might be more efficient.